# ms botframework attachment can not generate sharelink

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, chatbot

I use botframework api to send message to users.
the message contains attachment.
So I send the activity like this

```json
{
  "attachments": [{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.info",
    "contentUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/personal/johnadams_contoso_com/Documents/Applications/file_example.txt",
    "name": "file_example.txt",
    "content": {
      "uniqueId": "1150D938-8870-4044-9F2C-5BBDEBA70C8C",
      "fileType": "txt",
    }
  }]
}
```

And I send bot message to user like this
[image: message sent to bot]

And I want to generate sharelink by clicking this button
[image: generate link by clicking button]

But I got a error that told me I can's generate sharelink
[image: error]

Does anyone knows the reason?

Comment: What is the error message in English pls?

Comment: I found the problem is caused by uniqueID is not passed correctly. I passed it with the item id in one drive, but the unique id is not item id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is confirmed by the original post that it's caused by incorrect **uniqueID**. The uniqueID is not the itemID in one drive.

For more information about different IDs for botframework, please refer to document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-identifiers-guide?view=azure-bot-service-3.0